# cannot resolve symbol 'add' List<com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng>

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to use PolyUtil.*isLocationOnPath* and it is asking for `java.util.Listcom.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng` not `java.util.List com.google.type.LatLng` . As a result, when I try to create a list like so:

```
 List<com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng> path3 = new ArrayList<>();
 path3.add(new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(-35.016, 143.321),
           new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(-34.747, 145.592),
           new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(-34.364, 147.891),
           new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(-33.501, 150.217),
           new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(-32.306, 149.248),
           new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(-32.491, 147.309))

 public boolean checkLocationOnRoute(){
   return  onRoute = PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(currentPoint, path, false, 100);
 }
```

This results in a `cannot resolve symbol 'add'` error. How can I create the List for the **polyline** using the required `List<com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng>` and for the *isLocationOnPath* method.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a **polyline** like this

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true);
options.add(new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(-35.016, 143.321));
options.add(new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(-34.747, 145.592));
// Add all remaining points
Polyline line = mgGoogleMap.addPolyline(options);
```

Now you can check whether your point lies in the polyline like this:

```
PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(currentPoint, line.getPoints(), true)
// The true here refers to geodesic true.
```

Comment: It's still giving me a 'cannot resolve symbol 'add' error.
I tried placing the code to create the polyline into its own class which took away the 'cannot resolve symbol 'add' error but ended up not being able to access options object which holds the polyline points. Then when I added the line containing Polyline line into the class then I am unable to access line.getPoints. I tried creating a getter method but that didn't work. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: So, now, I am getting this error: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process:  PID: 31150
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.android.: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3841)

when I put the option add like this: public PolylineOptions getOptions() {
}

Comment: @lifespunchingbag It looks like mgGoogleMap is null when you are using addPolyline. Can you verify once if it's null ?

Comment: I was able to figure it out @May Rest In Peace. The error came from the .addPolyline. I just decided to try placing everything into a method since the 'cannot resolve symbol' error went away when it was in a class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the `.add(new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(Lat, Lng));` was throwing a `cannot resolve symbol 'add'`, I placed all of following code below inside my `requestLocationUpdates` method:

`List<com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng> options = new ArrayList<>();`

```
                options.add(new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(-35.016, 143.321));
                options.add(new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(-34.747, 145.592));// Add all remaining points                    

                onRoute = PolyUtil._isLocationOnPath_(currentPoint, options, true, 490);
```

I also tested it out using 490m as the `tolerance` and it returned `true` when the `currentPoint` was within distance and then `false` when the `currentPoint` was out of range from the coordinates in `options`.